# Getting a list of currently logged on users from the active directory

Tags: sharepoint-2010, directoryservices

I am currently working on developing a sharepoint 2010 web part where I need to get a list of currently logged on users from a given domain. Can this be done using  System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement? If so  how can some one give me code example?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to integrate with a 3rd party software like [Active Directory Network Manager](http://logicdevelopment.net/adnm/)